# Is it advised to push yarn.lock when we don’t have any new dependency?

Tags: reactjs, push, yarnpkg

If package.json didn’t suffer any modifications, do we still have to push yarn.lock?

When:

1. I delete node_modules folder
2. I Delete yarn.lock file and
3. I run the yarn install command,

Even if I didn’t add anything to the package.json, the yarn.lock will be generated with a different configuration.

So, as we have all the dependencies we need to run the project in package.json is it important to commit yarn.lock if we didn’t change package.json?

Comment: If your lockfile changed it means you have a new dependency or updated/downgraded an existing one. You should commit it at this point.

Comment: It's not clear what scenario you're asking about. Changes should be pushed, if there weren't any changes, there's no change to push.

Answer (score 1):

No, if there are no modifications in the dependency you can skip the lock file.
This file locks the dependencies with the versions installed.